# Textview in Linear Layout Appears on the wrong position

Tags: android, layout

I have the Below Layout. I want the linear layout that holds the  Textviews to appear below the PieChart. However it appears on top and on smaller screens the piechart overlays over the text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/catexprpt_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<com.echo.holographlibrary.PieGraph
    android:id="@+id/piegraph"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRowN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/piegraph"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:text="@string/note"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notice3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the `PieGraph` as a child of the `LinearLayout`.

I'm not sure about `ActionBarSherlock's` `PullToRefreshLayout` but the Android implementation `SwipeRefreshLayout` supports only one direct child view.

Edit:
I'm suggesting something like this as an only child to the Refresh layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <com.echo.holographlibrary.PieGraph
        android:id="@+id/piegraph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/piegraph"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:text="@string/note"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notice3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/piegraph"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

More on layout optimization [here.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)

Comment: If I use the 'PieGraph' as a child of the 'Linear Layout' I will have to add another linear layout to host the Textviews as their orientation should be Horizontal.

Comment: @Jaymo You can switch to `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Is this what you are suggesting <RelativeLayout <PieGraph /> <LinearLayout <TextView>  <TextView>   </LinearLayout>
    
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: The RelativeLayout would work but the Textviews need to be horizontal to each other (In a line if you may), at the bottom of the piechart. Hence my query on weather I need to child a LinearLayout at the bottom of the PieChart

Comment: @Jaymo try to set the gravity of PullToRefreshLayout to bottom.

Comment: I think I solved It...Let me Edit my question to show the solution

Comment: @Jaymo don't edit the question to show the solution. You can write your own answer

Comment: Let me write my own answer then

Comment: @LordRaydenMK thanks for the inspiration on the relativelayout

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it as below  thanks to  @ LordRaydenMK :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.extras.actionbarsherlock.PullToRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/catexprpt_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRowM"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <com.echo.holographlibrary.PieGraph
       android:id="@+id/piegraph"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/tableRowN"
       android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRowN"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/titleN"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
       android:text="@string/note"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:textSize="13sp"
       android:typeface="serif" />


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notice3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Heloooooo Mr. Fish"
        android:typeface="serif" />

 </LinearLayout>
```